# How to identify an object inside a nested array and delete the index based on a condition in JS forLoop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, lodash

I have this array of nested object in which the unique identifier is UUID

```
"statement":[
     {
        "boolean":"AND",
        "statement":[
           {
              "name":"long",
              "table":"testOne",
              "uuid":"cbb7e16b-42fc-4914-8119-cc51434ecb35",
           },
           {
              "boolean":"AND",
              "statement":[
                 {
                    "name":"float",
                    "table":"testOne",
                    "uuid":"87cac127-dda3-4435-ad1f-ae7e1a718f64",
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
]
```

And i have one more object

```
{
  "name":"float",
  "table":"testOne",
  "uuid":"87cac127-dda3-4435-ad1f-ae7e1a718f64",
}
```

Can i trace inside the nested object of statements and delete a particular object in the JSON based on UUID?

Comment: so you want to delete the mentioned below object from your json?What exactly do you mean by particular index?

Comment: Yes. i would like to trace inside the nested json and delete that object based on UUID. Have made necessary edits

Comment: is this json structured defined or it can be more nested ?

Comment: JSON can be nested to more levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this below, this will delete the desired object by going recursively.

```
mainFunction(){
                 let jsonData = {
                    "statement": [
                        {
                            "boolean": "AND",
                            "statement": [
                                {
                                    "name": "long",
                                    "table": "testOne",
                                    "uuid": "cbb7e16b-42fc-4914-8119-cc51434ecb35",
                                },
                                {
                                    "boolean": "AND",
                                    "statement": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "float",
                                            "table": "testOne",
                                            "uuid": "87cac127-dda3-4435-ad1f-ae7e1a718f64",
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };
                let searchObj = {
                    "name": "float",
                    "table": "testOne",
                    "uuid": "87cac127-dda3-4435-ad1f-ae7e1a718f64",
                };
                recursion(jsonData['statement'], searchObj);
            }


            recursion(data_list, obj){
               data_list.map(function (item, index) {
                   if(!item.hasOwnProperty('statement')){
                       if(item['uuid'] == obj['uuid']) {
                           data_list.splice(index, 1);
                           return data_list
                       }
                   }else{
                       recursion(item['statement'], obj)
                   }
               });
               return data_list
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you get the desired result.

```
let statement = [{
"boolean":"AND",
"statement":[
    {
        "name":"long",
        "table":"testOne",
        "uuid":"cbb7e16b-42fc-4914-8119-cc51434ecb35",
    },
    {
        "boolean":"AND",
        "statement":[{
            "name":"float",
            "table":"testOne",
            "uuid":"87cac127-dda3-4435-ad1f-ae7e1a718f64",
        }]
    }
]}];

let removeObj = {
   "name":"float",
   "table":"testOne",
   "uuid":"87cac127-dda3-4435-ad1f-ae7e1a718f64",
}

function checkUUID(arr) {
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty('uuid')) {
          if(removeObj.uuid === arr[i].uuid) {
            delete arr[i];
          } else {
            console.log('value not equal');
          }
       } else {
          checkUUID(arr[i].statement)
       }
    }
};

checkUUID(statement[0].statement);
```